# Can I assign a custom FQDN for an Amazon EKS cluster?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-eks, amazon-route53

When I run `aws eks update-kubeconfig`, my `~/.kube/config` file contains the following line:

```
    server: https://1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF.xx0.region.eks.amazonaws.com
```

This hostname resolves to some IP address in our VPC.

Which used to work fine, but now my company is migrating to a DNS-based VPN and, due to factors outside my team's control, blanket DNS routing of a domain we don't control, such as `eks.amazonaws.com`, is not an option. Also the server hostnames are constantly changing because we use Blue-Green Deployment.

There's a really crappy workaround in which we manually keep a CNAME record in Route53 and manually edit that address in kube config after we run `update-kubeconfig`.

Is there a way to tell EKS to use a Route53 Record instead of that amazonaws.com URLs in a way that `update-kubeconfig` will know about?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is the core discovery system for EKS, Kubernetes. Having said that, a potential solution is [external DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) which integrates with Route53.